# isAlpha(str) is method converting Persian into Unicode characters and return true

Tags: java, string, apache-stringutils, isalpha

I am trying to get data only in English language.
[image]
I tried different methods like:

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String s){
return s != null && s.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
}
```

Or `StringUtils` as:

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String str){
    return StringUtils.isAlpha(str);
    }
```

OR using Java:

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String s){
        if (s == null) {return false;}
 
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (!(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') && !(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
    }
```

Output is: `true`
I printed the string and found that aforementioned methods are converting Persian String into unicode as: `&#1670;&#1591;&#1608;&#1585;&#1740;`

Is there anyway to get String of only alphabet letters and spaces?

Comment: Make sure you understand how your input is transformed, to confirm that these are indeed XML numeric entities, then look for a solution to unescape/decode these into the proper Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

finally the following piece of code fixed my problem:

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String str){
        boolean isValid = false;
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') && !(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') && !(c == ' ')) {
                isValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    return isValid;
    }
```

Its only accepting:
a-z `(!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')` or 
A-Z `!(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` and 
white spaces `!(c == ' '))`

Thanks